# Carbocation ring expansion jump

Tags: carbocation

[image]

is the given rearrangement possible {major product}? from cyclo butane derivative to cyclohexane derivative.

Comment: How did you come up with this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzIfHpZiAXY

Comment: Q-7 of the video